# Check if a 4 by 4 matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Given a 4 by 4 matrix, I was wondering how to find the conditions on the entries to guarantee that the matrix is positive definite. All the entries in the matrix are non-zero, so if I directly compute the eigenvalues or calculate the leading principle minors, it would be a bit complicated.

Comment: See if you can use [Gershgorin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) if the matrix is diagonal dominant.

Comment: There is [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), which is easy to compute. Just include your matrix here and I can tell you.

Comment: Can also recommend the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) to reduce the problem to dealing with $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Sylvester's criterion, i.e. the positivity of leading principal minors, is a necessary and sufficient condition. But a necessary condition for positive definiteness is the positivity of all principal minors, not only the leading ones. For a symbolic matrix, the added inequalities can help in simplifying the main conditions

Comment: I take it your matrix is symmetric. That's a necessary condition for a matrix to be positive definite.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! I think all of them will work!